# How to export amodel from blender with textures and animations to use the model in Irrlicht?

Tags: animation, texturing

I am creating a small game using the Irrlicht engine. I have created a human model using MakeHuman and I have imported it in Blender. I am a total beginner to 3D I have created some basic animations in the model. MakeHuman already applied textures to the model, so I think It does not need to be done again. How to export the human model with textures and animations to use it in Irrlicht?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the Irrlicht Feature page, the engine supports the follow for fomats and texture types.

- Direct import of common mesh file formats: Maya (.obj), 3DStudio (.3ds), COLLADA (.dae), Blitz3D (.b3d), Milkshape (.ms3d), Quake 3 levels (.bsp), Quake2 models (.md2), Microsoft DirectX (.X)… [more]
- Direct import of Textures: Windows Bitmap (.bmp), Portable Network Graphics (.png), Adobe Photoshop (.psd), JPEG File Interchange Format (.jpg), Truevision Targa (.tga), ZSoft Painbrush (.pcx)… [more]

In order to export the mesh, you need to select the various components, then from the File -> Export menu you have a variety of options to choose from. See image.

After you have it exported then its a case of doing the engine side stuff.

[image: Export Menu]

Comment: It looks like Irrlicht does not support animations for formats like COLLADA / DAE: http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/?page_id=45#supportedformats http://irrlicht.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=21068
It would be nice to have explanations on how to export to a format that supports animations, like OP asked, for example exporting to a B3D file (which I did not see available in Blender export by default).